# Unable to display multiple columns using radioButtons in Shiny

Tags: r, input, datatable, shiny, dt

Hope you all are well. I'm facing a problem in the **reactive part of server** (if else statements).
Upon selection of **TTS** and **NTTS** using *radioButtons* i require columns from 1:6 and 7:11 of mtcars data respectively. I have attached pictures which matches the desired output. 
I also attached my codes, can someone please figure out whats wrong with them?
Many thanks :)

[image: when 'NTTS' selected]

[image: when 'TTS' selected]

[image: when 'All' is selected]

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(DT) 

data_table <- mtcars

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
downloadButton('downLoadFilter',"Download the filtered data"),

radioButtons(inputId = "columns", label = "choose variable",
    choices =c("All","TTS", "NTTS"),
    selected = c("All")),

selectInput(inputId = "cyl",
    label = "cyl:",
    choices = c("All",
                unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
    selected = "4",
    multiple = TRUE),

selectInput(inputId = "vs",
    label = "vs:",
    choices = c("All",
                unique(as.character(data_table$vs))),
    selected = "1",
    multiple = TRUE),

DT::dataTableOutput('ex1'))

server <- function(input, output) {

thedata <- reactive({

if(input$columns=='All'){
data_table
}

else if  (input$columns== 'TTS'){
data_table<-  data_table[,c(1:6),drop=FALSE]    }

else   
data_table<-  data_table[,c(7:11),drop=FALSE]

if(input$cyl != 'All'){
data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in%   input$cyl,]
}

if(input$vs != 'All'){
data_table<-data_table[data_table$vs %in%  input$vs,]
}

else
data_table })

output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(filter = 'top',
                                        escape = FALSE, 
                                        options = list(pageLength = 
                                                         10, 
scrollX='500px',autoWidth = TRUE),{
                                                 thedata() # Call reactive 

}))

output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
},
content = function(path){
write_csv(thedata(),path) # Call reactive thedata() 
})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Doctor. Could you work on your question to make it minimal https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, that is, remove code until you've isolated the problem? Could you clarify " I'm unable to do so": could you show the research and experiments you've done so far? Also could you reformulate the question so it asks about specifics rather than "could you help me debug this code?"

Comment: done, can you please review it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has little to do with Shiny or Datatable, it comes from how we subset and overwrite the data.
If we subset on columns first and overwrite `data_table`, one of `vs` or `cyl` is no longer present, and filtering rows based on a missing column results in `NULL`, all rows are lost.

Simple fix: reorder the subsetting, filter on rows first, then on columns:

```
  thedata <- reactive({
    if (!"All" %in% input$cyl) {
      data_table <- data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl, ]
    }
    if (!"All" %in% input$vs) {
      data_table <- data_table[data_table$vs %in% input$vs, ]
    }
    if (input$columns == "TTS") {
      data_table <- data_table[, c(1:6), drop = FALSE]
    }
    if (input$columns == "NTTS") {
      data_table <- data_table[, c(7:11), drop = FALSE]
    }
    data_table
  })
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) your a genius